# Connect to DynamDB using python language in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am families with working of Lambda function. But the thing here is i am trying to figure out how can i establish connection with my DynamDB using python.

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
```

I found this above code , but this is when i am using AWS SDK.

My use case is to have a sever less have a API set up to trigger a Lambda function to operate CRUD function DynamoDB.

Could some one suggest me a way to connect to my DynamoDB which is present in us-east-1?

Comment: The optional use of endpoint_url is documented at [Session.resource()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you have is for connecting to a local DynamoDB.

To do this for a region it is as simple as using the below

```
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
```

Alternatively you can set this in the session using the below example

```
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name="us-east-1")
```

I would suggest to take a look at using an [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) to set the region you call here so that you could reuse in other regions in the future with a bit of ease.

Comment: could you help me out with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283009/updateexpression-taking-dynamic-values-for-update-function-in-dynamodb-table-usi