# UpdateExpression taking dynamic values for update function in DynamoDB table using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

This is two part question for first part
[Updating the value of DynamoDB table with boto3 implemented lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267747/updating-the-value-of-dynamodb-table-with-boto3-implemented-lambda-function)

now what i am trying to achieve is having dynamic value to update

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    param = event['queryStringParameters']['employeID']
    name = event['queryStringParameters']['employeName']
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
    table = dynamodb.Table('api_demo_employe')
    column = [cloumn1,cloumn2......]
    for i in range(0,len(column):

       query = 'SET {} = :f'.format(column[i])

       response = table.update_item(
           Key = {
               'employeID' : param
           },
           ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    
              ':f': name
          },
           UpdateExpression = query
    
          )
```

I am getting an error

```
 "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Cannot update attribute employeID. This attribute is part of the key",
```

I know the issue is with how i am handling **UpdateExpression**

Could any one help me put with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re trying to update the item’s key, which doesn’t work. You will have to delete and recreate the item.

For details, please refer to the [Amazon DynamoDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html):

> You cannot use `UpdateItem` to update any primary key attributes. Instead, you will need to delete the item, and then use `PutItem` to create a new item with new attributes.